# bazel 0.21.0 install from installer fails on ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, ubuntu-18.04

I want to install **tensorflow-1.13.0-rc2**.
But when I want to install **bazel 0.21.0** on ubuntu **18.04.1**, the steps I take don't work.

At the directory of my installer, I run:

```
$sudo apt-get install pkg-config zip g++ zlib1g-dev unzip
$chmod +x bazel-0.21.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
$./bazel-0.21.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh --user
```

Then I edit the bashrc file by adding this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

(Then I save the file and run the shell; afterwards, I restart the terminal of ubuntu.)

The above steps follow [this link](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.21.0/install-ubuntu.html).

Finally when I run

```
bazel version
```

terminal gives me

> Command 'bazel' not found, did you mean:
>
> command 'babel' from deb openbabel
>
> Try: sudo apt install

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully watch the differences between my steps and official website....
I don't know why but I found that

```
$sudo apt-get install pkg-config zip g++ zlib1g-dev unzip
```

is wrong.

```
$sudo apt-get install pkg-config zip g++ zlib1g-dev unzip python
```

is the correct one.

Re-run those steps, and bazel 0.21.0 is indeed installed.